# Angular2 check if button is pressed

Tags: angular

How can I check if a button is pressed or not?

```
<anotherComponent [isPressedOkButton]="xxx">    
<button #okButton>
```

p.s In JSF exists such opportunity - "not empty param[button.clientId]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a variable inside of your Component if you want to do it with an input of another component. And set this variable if the button was pressed.

```
<another-component [isPressedOkButton]="btn.attachedProp"></another-component>
<button #btn (click)="yourClickFunction(); btn.attachedProp = true;"></button>
```

See a working demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/AUN40WbtoQDK4PkS4a61?p=preview

```js
import {Component, NgModule, Input} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-other',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h4>other component...</h4>
      button of main component was {{buttonIsPressed ? '' : 'NOT'}} pressed.
    </div>
  `,
})
export class OtherCmp {

  @Input() buttonIsPressed = false;

  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <button #btn (click)="btn.anyAttachedProperty = true;">click me ! :)</button>
      <br />
      <my-other [buttonIsPressed]="btn.anyAttachedProperty"></my-other>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {

  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, OtherCmp ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: No,dear mxii. I want know whether button pressed ?.And pass it to another coomponent as @Input.

Comment: See edited answer, you could do it like this way without an `@Input`.. otherwise you have to add some code to your question!

Comment: So,I should kepp boolean variable.With Component functions it is imposiible?

Comment: Yes you will need a variable.. I don't know what you exactly want to achieve.. so describe your use case or do it like described. :)

Comment: for example JSF  has that oportunity,without keeping variable
`  
 <h:inputHidden >
             <f:attribute name="process"
                         value=" **#{not empty param[buttonBinding.clientId]**"/>
  </h:inputHidden>
<p:commandButton  binding="#{buttonBinding}">
`

Comment: I don't know JSF, but I had another idea.. See my updated answer! We can attach a property to the button and reuse it as input-value for your component.. so all is done in your template